# APP engine blocking SSL in android webview

Tags: android, reactjs, google-app-engine, webview

I have this following URL

https://appprofreact-363918.rj.r.appspot.com/
But it has been blocked as soon as the webview is being open in webview version 99.0.4844.88 and the whole application stops. Could anyone assist us into how to overcome this problem? Most phones access the URL normally, just some devices and it's not clear if all of them have the same version of the webview.